# inline blob in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

whose hex dump is follows

00000000:   30001100 013caae4 62010000 00000000 †0....<..b.......
00000010:   00060040 02002000 5c803801 02000000 †...@.. ..8.....
00000020:   0400004d 01000000 384c0000 681f0000 †...M....8L..h...
00000030:   e7010000 01000000 d03e0000 08020000 †.........>......
00000040:   01000000 385e0000 09020000 01000000 †....8^..........
00000050:   926b0000 0a020000 01000000 ††††††††††.k..........

one of the column in the record is as follows

imageval = [BLOB Inline Root] Slot 2 Column 5 Offset 0x20 Length 60

Level = 0                            Unused = 77                          UpdateSeq = 1
TimeStamp = 1278738432
Link 0

Size = 8040                          RowId = (1:487:0)
Link 1

Size = 16080                         RowId = (1:520:0)
Link 2

Size = 24120                         RowId = (1:521:0)
Link 3

Size = 27538                         RowId = (1:522:0)

how can one identify whether it is [BLOB Inline Root].
How do we interpret the above values from hex.
Thanks

Comment: not even close to a real question...

Comment: A hex dump and a bunch of mysterious keywords, that's how I want to start my week!

Answer (score 1):

We'll need the table schema to identify the stored values...

That being said:

```
3000 =>  
The two first flag bytes of the record.

1100 =>  
Length of the fixed length data (decimal value = 17), meaning the next 13 bytes are the fixed length data portion of the record.

013caae4 62010000 00000000 00 =>  
Fixed length data. No way to say what's what without schema.

0600 =>  
Total number of columns in the table.

40 =>  
The null bitmap array. Decimal 64 = 0b10000000 in binary, meaning the first column of the record is NULL.

0200 =>  
Number of variable length columns. Thus we can conclude you have 4 fixed-length columns since the total is 6.

2000 =>
Position offset of first variable length column. Decimal value 32. Data can thus be found from position 27-32 for a total of 6 bytes: 3801 02000000.

5c80 =>
Position offset of second variable length column. Decimal value 32.860, 0b1000000001011100 in binary. BLOB pointers are identified using the sign bit of the position offset value. Removing the sign bit from the equation gives a decimal value of 0b0000000001011100 = 92. The inline data can thus be found from bytes 33-92:

0400004d 01000000 384c0000 681f0000
e7010000 01000000 d03e0000 08020000
01000000 385e0000 09020000 01000000
926b0000 0a020000 01000000

BLOB Inline Roots start out with a header:

04 =>  
Special field type

00 =>  
Link

00 =>  
Index level

4d =>
Unused (field)

01000000 =>  
Update sequence

384c0000 =>  
Timestamp (unsigned)

And then finally we have the actual meat, an array of slot pointers:

Length   PageID   FileID  Slot
681f0000 e7010000 0100    0000
d03e0000 08020000 0100    0000
385e0000 09020000 0100    0000
926b0000 0a020000 0100    0000
```